# PHP RestServer Class - Ajax call

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, rest, xmlhttprequest

I'm practicing with the PHP RestServer Class. But I can't get the correct data from it if I use an Ajax call on it. I have the following code:

```
<?php

require_once "locationOfRestServer.php";

class HelloWorld
{
    public static function sayHello()
    {
        return array("Response" => "Hello World");
    }
}

$rest = new RestServer('HelloWorld');
$rest->handle();
```

And in my javascript file I use the following:

```
this.helloWorld = function() {
    $.ajax({
        url: 'locationOfHelloWorld.php'
        type: 'POST',
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function(data){
            console.log(data);
        }
    });
};
```

I get the following [error](/questions/tagged/error):

> error: "No method was requested."

Because; whenever I use it, I have to go to `localhost/HelloWorld.php?method=sayHello` which is actually working.
So I added the following line to the ajax call:

> method: 'sayHello',

But it still keeps giving me the same error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this,

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'locationOfHelloWorld.php'
    type: 'GET',// use GET method according to your working url
    data:{method: 'sayHello'},// use method in data parameter
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function(data){
        console.log(data);
    }
});
```

Comment: I don't know if it was you which just posted a suggestion to change the link in the Ajax call, but that actually worked. I used the following: 
'url: 'location/HelloWorld.php?method=sayHello' - Which actually worked. I just don't know if it is the 'clean' solution for it? Did this without extending the rest server by the way. Why do I need to do so?

Comment: Used your example instead of mine now, working fine. Thanks. =)